# Toilet on septic system won't flush after heavy rain

Tags: plumbing

I have a home with 2 toilets on a septic system. It has been raining for 2 weeks or more. Neither toilet will flush. They just fill to the top of the bowl and take all day to drain. The first thing that happened before this problem was when in the shower the toilets had a lot of air bubble up and then the tube was draining slowly also.

Some people said to wait 2-3 days after the rain stops and the water that soaked into the septic would drain out and every thing would be ok.

Answer (score 2):

Your drain field is saturated.  You need a new drain field.  The drain field gets plugged with lint and fibers.  It is too slow to handle the drainage from your house when the ground is wet.  Talk to a qualified backhoe operator. He should be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

When is the last time you have the tank pumped out?  Call a company and have it pumped out if you haven't had it pumped out in the last 3-5 yrs.  Also can you tell us the size of your tank?

Answer (score 0):

It does not necessary mean anything is broken or you need a new system. The ground can only take so much water so fast. Depending on the type of dirt you have, your system will drain accordingly. For example. 1 inch of rain over an acre is 27,000 gallons of water. That’s a lot of water for the ground to absorb. Leach fields are only designed to take a small amount of water every day. Say a few hundred gallons.